# How to use the copy method simply in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

my code :

```
@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self, default=None):
    default = dict(default)
    return self.env['ecole.partner.school'].copy(default)
```

My error :

ValueError : Expected singleton: ecole.partner.school()

Why ? Thanks

Comment: You must call copy() from a specific record, not from an empty recordset (`self.env['ecole.partner.school']`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the mistake is always the same

Comment: Could you please write down in more detail what you want to achieve? Why do you want to copy something with a button? What is `default`? A button method won't fill `default` with whatever you want, actually IIRC the context will be placed in it. Button methods should only have one parameter: self.

Comment: I want to be able to duplicate a line and change some field values ​​but not all values. I do not know what is the exact method and I am Odoo beginner :) For the "default", I took example in the documentation of Odoo. Thank you

Comment: `A line` means you have a `Many2many` or `One2many` relation on a model and want to duplicate one of its entries?

Comment: No, a line is a record in the database, I did not express myself correctly

Comment: It is really simple, just go through the account copy method

Answer (score -2):

```
@api.multi
def button_for_run_update(self, default=None):
    default = dict(default)
    for eps in self:
        eps.copy(default)
        ecole = self.env['ecole.partner.school'].id  # need ID here
        ecole.create(default)
    return True
```

With this recordset, you may have something like ecole.partner.school(1,2,…). You need to specify an ID.